# Count the permutations which are products of exactly two disjoint cycles.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

> Let $a_n$ be the number of those permutation $\sigma $ on $\{1,2,...,n\}$  such that $\sigma $ is a product of exactly two disjoint cycles. Then find $a_4$ and $a_5$.

Calculating $a_4$: Possible cases which can happen are $(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)$, any cycle of the form $(123)$ or $(12)$ i.e. two-cycles and three cycles thus we have in total $3+\frac{1}{3}4P_3+\frac{1}{2}4P_2=3+8+6=17$ but the correct answer is given to be either $11$ or $14$.

Where am I wrong? Please help.

Comment: Does a cycle with one element count as a cycle - that is, is $(123)=(123)(4)$ the product of two cycles or one?

Comment: Judging from the question (and possible answers) I presume that only cycles of the form $(x_{i_1}\dots x_{i_k})(x_{i_{k+1}}\cdots x_{n})$ with $1\le k \le n-1$ have to be counted. So you should not count $(12)$ in the case of $4$ elements as a product of two cycles, as it is actually $(12)(3)(4)$ whereas you should definitely count $(123)(4)$.

Comment: If you don't count the $(12)$ form, you get $11$. Perhaps they meant, since $(12)=(12)(3)(4)$ in "normal form," then it is not, in normal form, the product of exactly two cycles. Would depend on the exact wording of the question.

Comment: I don't understand why people are finding this question unclear. What possible reason could there be for not counting a cycle of length $1$ as a cycle?

Comment: @DerekHolt: Because it says "$\sigma$ is a product of exactly two disjoint cycles". If it said "the cycle decomposition of $\sigma$ contains exactly two cycles", that would be clear. But any permutation whose cycle decomposition contains exactly two cycles with length greater $1$ is the product of those exactly two cycles.

Comment: @jonki yes I see your point! I was probably using experience to guess what they probabyl meant!

Answer (score 5):

Let $r\in[1\>..\>n-1]$ be the length of the cycle containing  the number $n$. Begin the listing of this cycle with $n$. There are $(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-r+1)$ ways to choose the remaining entries of this cycle. Now there will be $n-r\geq1$ numbers left over, one of them the largest. Begin the listing of the second cycle with this largest left-over number, and you will then have $(n-r-1)!$ ways to choose the remaining entries of the second cycle. In all we have ${(n-1)!\over n-r}$ permutations of this kind. It follows that there are
$$a_n=(n-1)!\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{1\over k}\tag{1}$$
elements of $S_n$ having exactly two cycles. In particular this gives $a_4=11$. – Maybe the formula $(1)$ can be brought into a closed form, using some combinatorial identity.

Computing the $a_n$ we obtain the sequence $(1, 3, 11, 50, 274, 1764, 13068, 109584, 1026576,\ldots)$ which OEIS identifies as [A000254](http://oeis.org/A000254).

Answer (score 2):

From the possible answers, it appears that the question intended to ask how many permutations have exactly two cycles in their cycle decomposition, including the $1$-cycles.

If the smaller cycle has $k$ elements, the greater has $n-k$, and $j$ particular elements can form $(j-1)!$ different $j$-cycles. Thus the desired count is

$$
\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom nk(k-1)!(n-k-1)!=\frac{n!}2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{k(n-k)}\;,
$$

where the factor $\frac12$ compensates for the double-counting of all products, including in the case of even $n$ the products of two cycles of length $\frac n2$. So we have

$$
a_4=4!\left(\frac1{1(4-1)}+\frac12\frac1{2(4-2)}\right)=24\left(\frac13+\frac18\right)=11
$$

and

$$
a_5=5!\left(\frac1{1(5-1)}+\frac1{2(5-2)}\right)=120\left(\frac14+\frac16\right)=50\;.
$$